# Adding an Existing Solution that was Previously a NuGet Package into a Single Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on stabilizing a rather old website so that development can resume on it by adding new features. The previous implementers however had a rather strange approach to modularity - their heart was in the right place, but the execution was... off.

There's one "Main" solution, which - as a front end guy, will typically work with. It includes the web project which is served by IIS. A lot of (pretty much all) the Back End stuff however, is brought in via a NuGet package from a private NuGet Server (TeamCity)

Now. This seems kind of nice and modular until you have to make a backend change. Previously, if a backend change was required, the team would make the change in the backend solution, and then ***commit and republish*** the entire package. The Front End solution must then update the NuGet Package on it's end in order to receive the changes.

*This is a nightmare...*

I won't even start on the version control situation. But lets just say branching hasn't been a known concept here for a number of years. But I'm here to put it on the straight and narrow.

I was wondering if anybody has had experience Adding and existing project to a solution that was previously a NuGet package. I added the entire Backend solution and removed the NuGet dependency, only for the build to blow up in my face declaring that the types from the Backend solution no longer existed.

I'm thinking I need to add these new projects to the build order or something? Maybe that's a red herring.

Yours sincerely,

*A JavaScript guy who's out of his depth with .NET...*

Answer (score 0):

Have you added references to the "new" backend in your front-end project? Right-click on the project Add -> reference... and select the backend project within Solution list.